# UIBarButtonItem - How do I make a "done" button pop?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, navigationcontroller

I got a navigation controller that has a "Done" button. When the user is finished with the form, they press "Done" and I want that view popped off the stack and back at the main menu.

Here is the code I got so far:

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                 target:self 
                                                                 action:[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES]];          
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
```

Please help! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Define new method of the class that corresponds to `self`. Fro example,

```
- (void)closeView
{
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
}
```

2) Set appropriate selector when creating your button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                             target:self 
                                                             action:@selector(closeView)];          
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
[anotherButton release]; // and don't forget to clear memory
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed that memory release too.. great save!

Answer (score 3):

How about you try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                 target:self 
                                                                 action:@selector(onClickOfDone);          
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
```

Now write the popViewController logic in the method named **onClickOfDone**

```
- (void)onClickOfDone {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

If your pop is only one level back then the above code would help. If you want to specifiy the controller to which it has to pop to, then you can use

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES]
```

EDIT:

You could also use the SystemItem for Done:

```
UIBarButtonItem *aDoneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone 
                                                                             target:self action:@selector(onClickOfDone)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = aDoneButton;
[aDoneButton release];
```

Comment: Ahh @selector() got me all tripped up! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct just make one function and inside that function write popping code, then call that function using `@selector` in action.